# Does Android SDK suggested with MVP design pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

I've read about `MVP` design pattern and have some question about it.

If we consider `Android SDK` we can suggest that an `Activity` is a `Presenter` which takes over event handling, lifecycle events executing and communication with data-layer which can be a `SharedPreferences`, `SQLlite` etc. View in that case is just `xml`- view description which doesn't contain any event handlers or other `user-communication` things.

But I'm doubt if my reasoning correct at all? Could you help me to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Android also follow MVC architecture.

1) In Android `activity` is the controller where you write a code for handling input & response.

2) `xml` layouts represent the view where you describe the presentation part of the application.

3) & model is your java `pojo` classes. For instance Person class which has two attributes first name & last name.

Comment: It seems you're right. I've been tring to googling and have found that android is MVC, but I can't find anything about MVP in android.

Comment: No Android does not quite follow MVC following this idea you will just end up with one huge untestable activity which will be spagetti code of interactment  and will not be maintainable in the long run! For anything complex you will need to encapusulate a "Presenter" whos responsibility is to bind the view with the model. I would suggest that you follow MVP.